# How can I configure PhpStorm to highlight both HTML and PHP syntax in a .html5 file?

Tags: phpstorm

I have to use this IDE at work. I also have to work on Contao templates which use the html5 extension.

I just got PhpStorm to recognize those files as HTML, big win, but it would be great if it would know what's up inside  too.

Comment: Assign `*.html5` pattern to **PHP Files** in **Settings | File Types**

Comment: Thank you, that worked. If you provide that as an answer I'll this question as answered.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assign `*.html5` pattern to **PHP Files** in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`

Comment: I had an issue when tried to enable highlighting and formatting of php blocks inside `.htm` files. I've added `*.htm` pattern for php file type, and PhpStorm warned me, that the existing assignment will be removed. If proceed, PhpStorm can start adding `.php` extension "on top of " the existing filenames; In my case it helped using `*.ht*` pattern instead, it matches anything with extension starting from `ht`.